# Check if Toplevel() object exists in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

RE: verifying the existence of a Toplevel()

I'm setting a 15-second time limit for the user as they choose whether they want a random  vowel or a random consonant, 9 times, to form a random list of letters. (I'm using a Toplevel containing a GUI timer which I got from someone else's answer).

If they manage it on time, a similar timer appears on the ORIGINAL window, replacing the vowel/consonant buttons (which I have destroyed at this point), and the old SEPARATE-window Toplevel timer is destroyed. However, I want to make the second countdown, since it HAS to start at 30 seconds, start at the right time, rather than ticking away in the background (behind the VOWEL/CONSONANT buttons) during which time the user is still selecting letters.

If none of that made any sense, then this is a basic outline of the code that doesn't work.

```
# I tried to test if the the Toplevel timer had been destroyed (which happens as soon as the 
# user has finished with the 9 letters). If so, I could then start the NEW 30-second timer.

import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

test = tk.Label() 


# above: later, will test if a Label() widget counts as a 'child'. If it was the case  
# that only Toplevels counted as 'children', then I could have used the 'root.winfo_children' 
# command to test if the Toplevel() timer had been destroyed, in which case I can start a new 
# 30-second timer on the original window.

test.pack()

extraWindow = tk.Toplevel(root)

extraWindow.destroy() # for below, to TRY and test whether the Toplevel object is destroyed

if not root.winfo_children():
    print("N0") # doesn't happen, because test label is also a 'child' 
    # IMAGINE that this is where I set off the NEW 30-second timer

root.mainloop()
```

Unfortunately, I have a label on the original window, displaying the list of letters as it develops in the fist 15 seconds, and while the user is coming up with a real word from as many of those letters as possible in the new, 30 seconds. I cannot use `winfo_children`. Is there something I can do to the effect of `winfo_Toplevel`?

*(EDIT: yes there is;* I finally did my homework and found something really obvious that I had missed, so, unfortunately, I answered my own question)

Answer (score 8):

Whoops I just found an answer to my own question.
You can check whether a top level exists using '`tkinter.Toplevel.winfo_exists(my_toplevel_name)`'.

If you put this in a print statement, it returns 1 if it does exist, and 0 if it does not.